# How to I curtail bots from bypassing the reCAPTCHA test we use on the sign-up page for our newsletter?

Tags: profile

We have a Profile that collects email addresses from new users and (after the user receives our confirmation email and confirms their email address to us) the Profile adds the user to a Group which we use for our newsletter distribution.  reCAPTCHA v2 is enabled on the Profile but CiviCRM is creating a lot (hundreds) of bogus new Contacts every day. (The new Contacts are not added to the Group because they don't respond to our confirmation email.) How to we stop/curtail bots from bypassing the reCAPTCHA test?
CiviCRM 5.66.0, WordPress 6.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [Form Protection](https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-protection) extension, which gives you additional measures to prevent abuse/bots, including Honeypot, Flood control, & ReCAPTCHA v3.